# Azure Search suggestions based on multiple terms

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an online grocery store, products have such attributes:

- product name (Pepsi, 7UP)
- container (1 bottle, 1 can)
- variant name (diet, max)

I want my Azure Search solution to suggest users required product regardless of search terms order (diet Pepsi, 1 can Pepsi, Pepsi 1 can), but with no luck.

I wonder, if the only way to do this is to compute a "keywords cloud" which will contain all possible permutations and use this "keywords cloud" field as a suggester field? Example of such "keywords cloud" field value: "Pepsi diet 1 can diet Pepsi 1 can Pepsi".

Azure Search search solution somehow does the trick, but I can't use it because it doesn't support typeahead (AFAIK).

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Cześć Maciej. Do you have suggester configured on all the fields in question? What are the queries you are issuing and what results do you get in return? I'm trying to understand what your expectations are.

Comment: Cześć Yahnoosh. Pablo already answered my question, but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions are built for cases where you want to progressively discover a short phrase. In your case it looks like what you want is to search for any word across the documents, in any order. For that you could simply issue a search request instead of a suggest request in each keystroke. That will execute a keyword search, which seems like it's what you're looking for.

If you want the last word to be treated as partial input, you could do the following trick assuming you target languages that separate words with whitespace: take the input text, split out the last word (i.e. go backwards from the end of the string until you find a non-character/number symbol) and then produce a string of the form "original-minus-last (last|last*)". For example, if the input is "Can Pepsi Di", you'd produce "Can Pepsi (Di|Di*)".

Comment: Is suggestions more performant than search? Are we going to loose anything by switching from Suggestions to Search?

Comment: Suggestions is generally faster than search, all other things being similar (conversely, if filters used in search and suggestions have very different selectivity you'll see different performance). Suggestions also don't support using scoring profiles to customize scoring.